# Plot Bezier Curve in Octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I'm trying to plot Bezier Curves in Octave. A Bezier curve is defined by a number of control points, for example:

[image]

I'm trying to plot something like this. I found out about a function: `drawBezierCurve` but the function needs four control points and I need to plot a a Bezier curve with just three points. The control points are: `a(1,2), b(4,-1), c(8,6)`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the lines **ab** and **bc**:

```
a = [1 2];
b = [4 -1];
c = [8 6];
```

[image: ab and ac]

Create n equidistant points on them:

```
npoints = 10;
line1 = linspace(a, b, npoints);
line2 = linspace(b, c, npoints);
```

[image: n points]

For the **k**th point on the Bézier curve, take **k / n** parts from first line and **(n - k) / n** parts from the second line.

```
weights = linspace(1, 0, npoints);
curve = line1 .* weights + line2 .* (1 - weights);
```

[image: points on bezier curve]

Connect the obtained points to draw the curve:

```
plot(curve(1, :), curve(2, :))
```

[image: bezier curve]

---

The complete code:

```matlab
a = [1 2];
b = [4 -1];
c = [8 6];

npoints = 10; % modify this
line1 = linspace(a, b, npoints);
line2 = linspace(b, c, npoints);
weights = linspace(1, 0, npoints);

curve = line1 .* weights + line2 .* (1 - weights);
plot(curve(1, :), curve(2, :))
```

---

Additional code to draw the figures in this answer:

```
fig = figure;
hold on

% figure 1
plot([a(1) b(1)], [a(2) b(2)])
plot([b(1) c(1)], [b(2) c(2)])

% figure 2
plot(line1(1, :), line1(2, :), 'ok')
plot(line2(1, :), line2(2, :), 'or')

% figure 3
plot([line1(1,:); line2(1, :)], [line1(2, :); line2(2, :)], 'm--')

plot(curve(1, :), curve(2, :), 'oc')

% figure 4
plot(curve(1, :), curve(2, :), 'b', 'linewidth', 2)
```

Comment: This code doesn't produce the same figure for me. Is there any package that should be installed?    ```a = [1 2];
b = [4 -1];
c = [8 6];
npoints = 10;
line1 = linspace(a, b, npoints);
line2 = linspace(b, c, npoints);
weights = linspace(1, 0, npoints);
curve = line1 .* weights + line2 .* (1 - weights);
plot(curve(1, :), curve(2, :));```

Comment: It should (only) produce the blue line at the last figure - the Bezier curve. I have added other drawings to explain what the code is doing. I can share the code I used to create them if you want.

Comment: That would be great. Please share de code because it doesn't draw the blue line right now. Thank you!

Comment: I have shared it. But the code you pasted *should* be drawing the blue line. If it is not working, please tell me what it draws (or what error you get if any).

Answer (score 2):

You can always reproduce the bezier curve equation (see [here](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/bezier-construct.html))

```
P   = [1,2; 4,-1; 8,6].';
B   = @(n,i,u) nchoosek(n, i) * u .^ i .* (1-u) .^ (n-i);
U   = [0:0.1:1];
Bez = B(2,0,U) .* P(:,1) + B(2,1,U) .* P(:,2) + B(2,2,U) .* P(:,3);

plot( Bez(1,:), Bez(2,:) );
```

[image]